# TextBox template padding issue

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am trying to re-template a `TextBox` to have two borders with padding in-between; however, even when I explicitly set the padding on the PART_`ContentHost` to zero, the padding for the control is always being applied to the inner `ScrollViewer` as well.

Small example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        Background="LightBlue">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="0" Margin="0" Background="Turquoise"
                                  x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<TextBox Padding="15"/>
```

The result is a textbox that looks like: [15[15 **Textfield** 15]15]

while I expected just: [15[ **Textfield** ]15]

How do I properly force the PART_ContentHost ( scrollviewer / textfield) to have a zero padding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This really looks like a weird bug to me unless someone has a better explanation for this behavior.

`ScrollViewer`(PART_ContentHost) internally uses a `Template` like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Grid x:Name="Grid"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Corner"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                            CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                            CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"
                Cursor="Arrow"
                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                Minimum="0"
                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                Value="{Binding VerticalOffset,
                                Mode=OneWay,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"
                Cursor="Arrow"
                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                Minimum="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset,
                                Mode=OneWay,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The interesting bit is:

```
<ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                        CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                        CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
```

**Now to fix your issue you can just set the Margin there to 0 instead of `{TemplateBinding Padding}` and you'll get your desired output.**

But why did we need to do that?

`TemplateBinding Padding` seems to be ignoring the value set directly on the `ScrollViewer` which is in the inner scope and picks the Padding value inherited from the Parent(`Button`) which is 15.

Ok that's weird, but what's worse is it's only for Padding. `Foreground`, `Background`, `Margin` are all fine when set directly on `ScrollViewer` they override the `TextBox`'s fields. I even to confirm moved the `Padding` set directly on the `TextBox` in usage to a default Style setter, to see if some precedence case was the problem.

It did not seem to be. Got same output.

Padding is defined in `System.Windows.Controls.Control` which is the same class Foreground and Background are from that `ScrollViewer` inherits. Not sure why padding alone is behaving differently.

I also tried changing the presenter to something like

```
<ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                        CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                        CanVerticallyScroll="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
```

It print's 15,15,15,15. Doesn't do that for the `Margin`.

Same effect with a `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=Padding}` binding.

I saw one post saying `ScrollViewer` does not pass properties set on it to it's children. Don't really get that since if that was the case how did `Background`, `Margin` and sorts be fine to over-ride? Whats so special about `Padding`? If it is valid behavior, I don't really see how to get rid of that behavior without Templating the `ScrollViewer` as well and it's one confusing implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed and well tested answer! I really appreciate the input and information regarding the scrollviewer template. This is certainly a strange case, which does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

This weird behavior is coming from `TextBoxBase`.
It overrides metadata for some of its dependency properties and for the `Padding` property it looks like:

```cs
Control.PaddingProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof (TextBoxBase), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        new PropertyChangedCallback(TextBoxBase.OnScrollViewerPropertyChanged)));
```

If you take a look at the `OnScrollViewerPropertyChanged` handler, you'll notice that it passes the value of the changed property to its `ScrollViewer`:

```cs
  if (newValue == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
    textBoxBase.ScrollViewer.ClearValue(e.Property);
  else
    textBoxBase.ScrollViewer.SetValue(e.Property, newValue);
```

So, no matter what `Padding` value you set in Control Template, it will be overwritten with the local value by `TextBox` in runtime.

To compensate this padding you can set a negative margin to `ScrollViewer` in the template:

```xml
<ScrollViewer 
    x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding, Converter={StaticResource InvertThicknessConverter}}"
/>
```

where `InvertThicknessConverter` is a value converter which negates every component of the passed thickness value:

```cs
public class InvertThicknessConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Thickness) return InvertThickness((Thickness)value);
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Thickness) return InvertThickness((Thickness)value);
        return value;
    }

    private static Thickness InvertThickness(Thickness value)
    {
        return new Thickness(-value.Left, -value.Top, -value.Right, -value.Bottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting find! Thanks for further details. While I will likely continue to use a custom scrollviewer style to get around the issue, it's great to have options, and to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted answer because you're just using a converter versus overriding a `ControlTemplate`; however, it only works if you bind to the `ScrollViewer`'s `Padding`, _not_ `Margin`, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when setting the `Padding` property on `DataGridColumnHeader`, and got around it by specifying a padding property close but not equal to zero:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomHeader" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
    <!-- Why you might ask do we need a value that is near but not actually 0?  No idea, but if it is not there, "4" is used. -->
    <!-- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424739/textbox-template-padding-issue -->
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0.000000000001,0" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here to find out how to set the padding in the textbox template properly:

Not only `ScrollViewer` could host your content. You can use `Decorator` instead. So taking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26300334/12305721)  into account you could make your template look like the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        Background="LightBlue">
                    <ScrollViewer Background="Turquoise">
                        <Decorator x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <ScrollViewer/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```